# 'KeyError: 0' accessing items

Tags: python, json, xml, dictionary

I am converting the XML data into JSON and then storing it in the database.
I am getting a key error 0. Error occurs in line12. The related code files are-

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import boxer.utils3 as utils3


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "it saves news."

    def handle(self,*args,**options):
      g1 = utils3.wegGetter("https://www.naukrinama.com/feed/")
      items = utils3.processor(g1)
      for i in range(0,len(items)):
         item = items[i] ##line12
         utils3.saver(item)
      return
```

The second file is-

```
import requests
import xmltodict
from . import models

def wegGetter(url):
   f1 = requests.get(url)
   g1 = xmltodict.parse(f1.content)
   return g1

def processor(content):
   items = content['rss']['channel']
   return items

def saver(item):
   title = item['title']
   category=item['category']
   description=item['description']
   image_url=item['post-thumbnail']
   url=item['link']
   _content = models.Content(cid="2",title=title,category=category,image_url=image_url,description=description,url=url)
   _content.save()
   return
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `items` is a dictionary, which do have a length corresponding to the number of (key, value) pairs they contain. However those items are referenced by their keys, which are arbitrary and not necessarily sequential numeric indices starting from `0` like they would be for a `list`.

Change the loop in the `handle()` method to this:

```
      ...
      items = utils3.processor(g1)
      for key, value items.items():
          utils3.saver(value)
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`processor` returns a dictionary, not a list: it has keys like `title`, `link`, etc.

There's no reason to have that for loop at all. Just pass `items` directly back to `saver`.

Note that if you did need to iterate, you should never do it with `range(len(whatever))` anyway. In the case of a dictionary, you should iterate over the items directly:

```
for key, value in items:
   ... do something with key and value...
```